# Pandas: Creating another column with row column multiplication

Tags: python, pandas

```
Priority     Expected    Actual 
High              47        30           
Medium            22        14           
Required          16         5
```

I'm trying to create two other columns '**Expected_values**' which will have the values like for the row **High 47*5**, for the row **Medium 22*3**,for the row **Required 16*10**  and '**Actual_values**' for the row **High 30*5**, for the row **Medium 14*3**,for the row **Required 5*10**

like this

```
Priority           Expected    Actual   Expected_values    Actual_values 
Required               16         5           160               50
High                   47        30           235              150 
Medium                 22        14            66               42
```

Any simple way to do that in pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
a = np.array([5, 3, 10])

df['Expected_values'] = df.Expected * a

df['Actual_values'] = df.Actual * a

print df

   Priority  Expected  Actual  Expected_values  Actual_values
0      High        47      30              235            150
1    Medium        22      14               66             42
2  Required        16       5              160             50
```

Comment: @AnuragChaudhary If this answers your question, mark it as the answer so others can benefit.